# PHP Echo include filename

Tags: php, apache, include, webserver, echo

Hi i just want to ask if how i can echo the include file script

---

```
**index.php**
<?php


include('inc.php');

?>
```

---

```
**inc.php**

<?php

echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;

?>
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

my files is located in localhost/test/file/

the out put of the script above is **/test/file/index.php**

What i want is the output should be **/test/file/inc.php**
Please help.

Comment: what is the output that you are getting with your current code..??

Comment: When you write `include('inc.php')`, you've already provided the path. I suppose you should store the path in a variable for your need later then. If you've only write `inc.php` it means it is placed the same directory with the script (you obtain by `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for something like this:

```
$pathToInc = dirname(__FILE__);
```

then you can just echo $pathToInc or whatever you name your variable from within your inc.php. This should output the path within that variable and not the patch of index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `__FILE__` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php